# logstash-forward equivalent for fluentd?

Tags: logstash, system-monitoring, fluentd, logstash-forwarder

Is there something equivalent to [logstash-forwarder](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder) that can ship logfiles to fluentd?

I am trying to send log files from an application to a remote fluentd but have not seen whether this is possible via an agent somehow. I understand that you can make fluentd read logfiles when it runs on the same machine where the logfiles are produced (or copied) but I would love it whether something equivalent to *logstash-forwarder* exists.

Some more information: The system is a Debian 7 and the application logs in a file line-by-line. No syslog capability and that is why I am seeking for agents like *logstash-forwarder* instead that sort of `tail -f logfile` and send each new line at the remote fluentd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the easiest way to do this would be to use the [syslog](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_syslog) input in Fluentd. But it would depend on the application you were sending from. Some more information about your environment would be helpful, like the OS you are sending from...

Edit: Debian Wheezy comes with rsyslog, I would recommend you use that.

Comment: I added some more in the description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to see whether this can be achieved with rsyslogd inputs.